# Plot coefficients with confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I have a sample regression as below. 

y<sub>it</sub> = λ<sub>i</sub> + δ<sub>t</sub> + α<sub>1</sub>TR + ∑  <sub>t ∈ {2,,,T}</sub>  β<sub>t</sub>TR*δ<sub>t</sub>

That is, I have time-varying coefficients, β<sub>t</sub>. With the regression result, I would like to plot coefficients with confidence intervals (X-axis is time and Y-axis is the coefficient values).

Here is the sample data

```
y = rnorm(1000,1)
weekid = as.factor(sample.int(52,size = 1000,replace = T))
id = as.factor(sample.int(100,size = 1000,replace = T))
tr = as.factor(sample(c(0,1),size = 1000, prob = c(1,2),replace = T))
sample_lm = lm(y ~ weekid + id + tr*weekid)
summary(sample_lm)
```

How can I plot coefficients for `tr*weekid` with the confidence intervals?

Comment: So what exactly do you want this plot to look like? If you use random numbers in your example, it's best to also include a `set.seed()` so we can get the same values as you to replicate the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `ggcoef` from `GGally`. One issue is that you want to visualize only a subset of coefficients. In that case we can do

```
ggcoef(tail(broom::tidy(sample_lm, conf.int = TRUE), 51), sort = "ascending")
```

[image]

**Update**: since, at least to some extent, we can deal with this graph as with a `ggplot2` output, we may flip the axes with `coord_flip`. That's not the best idea since the variable names are long, so just for demonstration I combined it with `angle = 30`. By default the coefficients are sorted by name, which again isn't what one may be after. As to fix that, we first need to define the coefficient names as a factor variable and specify their levels. That is, we have

```
tbl <- tail(broom::tidy(sample_lm, conf.int = TRUE), 51)
tbl$term <- factor(tbl$term, levels = tbl$term)
ggcoef(tbl) + coord_flip() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!. Is there a way of switching the X-axis and Y-axis? and, If I want to sort by week (from week2 ~ week 51)? Thank you in advance!!!